# How to solve gplots installing package problem in R?

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install `gplots` package and it needs `caTools` package but this package is working with R (≥ 3.6.0) only. I am using R 3.3.0, I used to use `gplots` package with this R version but I can't use it anymore. What is the main reason of this problem? There was no problem even in R 3.3.0 version to install gplots package. And also I need to use this R version for my works.

Devtools installing error:

```
install.packages("devtools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in readRDS(file) : 
  çalışma alanı sürümü 3 okunamıyor (R 4.1.0 ile yazılmış; R 3.5.0 ya da daha yenisi gerekli)
Error in readRDS(file) : 
  çalışma alanı sürümü 3 okunamıyor (R 4.1.0 ile yazılmış; R 3.5.0 ya da daha yenisi gerekli)
also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘yaml’, ‘xfun’, ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘git2r’, ‘glue’, ‘rematch2’, ‘processx’, ‘knitr’, ‘purrr’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘covr’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rlang’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘testthat’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
             binary source needs_compilation
yaml         2.1.18  2.2.1              TRUE
xfun            0.1   0.16             FALSE
fs            1.2.2  1.5.0              TRUE
gh            1.0.1  1.1.0             FALSE
git2r        0.21.0 0.27.1              TRUE
glue          1.2.0  1.4.1              TRUE
rematch2      2.0.1  2.1.2             FALSE
processx    2.0.0.1  3.4.3              TRUE
knitr          1.20   1.29             FALSE
purrr         0.2.4  0.3.4              TRUE
usethis       1.3.0  1.6.1             FALSE
callr         2.0.3  3.4.3              TRUE
cli           1.0.0  2.0.2             FALSE
covr          3.0.1  3.5.0              TRUE
jsonlite        1.5  1.7.0              TRUE
rcmdcheck     1.2.1  1.3.3             FALSE
rlang         0.2.0  0.4.7              TRUE
roxygen2      6.0.1  7.1.1              TRUE
sessioninfo   1.0.0  1.1.1             FALSE
testthat      2.0.0  2.3.2              TRUE
devtools     1.13.5  2.3.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ps’ ‘ellipsis’ ‘pkgload’
  These will not be installed
URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/yaml_2.1.18.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 185468 bytes (181 KB)
downloaded 181 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/fs_1.2.2.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 929393 bytes (907 KB)
downloaded 907 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/git2r_0.21.0.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 3022652 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/glue_1.2.0.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 72364 bytes (70 KB)
downloaded 70 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/processx_2.0.0.1.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 91282 bytes (89 KB)
downloaded 89 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/purrr_0.2.4.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 244026 bytes (238 KB)
downloaded 238 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/callr_2.0.3.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 1028797 bytes (1004 KB)
downloaded 1004 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/covr_3.0.1.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 121024 bytes (118 KB)
downloaded 118 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/jsonlite_1.5.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 1159497 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rlang_0.2.0.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 754726 bytes (737 KB)
downloaded 737 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/roxygen2_6.0.1.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 754056 bytes (736 KB)
downloaded 736 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/testthat_2.0.0.zip' deneniyor
Content type 'application/zip' length 1197604 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘purrr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘callr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘covr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘roxygen2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘xfun’, ‘gh’, ‘rematch2’, ‘knitr’, ‘usethis’, ‘cli’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘devtools’

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xfun_0.16.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 75746 bytes (73 KB)
downloaded 73 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gh_1.1.0.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 29043 bytes (28 KB)
downloaded 28 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rematch2_2.1.2.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13366 bytes (13 KB)
downloaded 13 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.29.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 885623 bytes (864 KB)
downloaded 864 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.6.1.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 255052 bytes (249 KB)
downloaded 249 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_2.0.2.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 116357 bytes (113 KB)
downloaded 113 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pkgbuild_1.1.0.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 29854 bytes (29 KB)
downloaded 29 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rcmdcheck_1.3.3.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 45380 bytes (44 KB)
downloaded 44 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sessioninfo_1.1.1.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46027 bytes (44 KB)
downloaded 44 KB

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.3.1.tar.gz' deneniyor
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 373604 bytes (364 KB)
downloaded 364 KB

* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="xfun.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="base64.o init.o"' komutunu çalıştırırken 127 durumu oluştu
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/xfun'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/xfun_0.16.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'rematch2' ...
** package 'rematch2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'pillar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rematch2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rematch2'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/rematch2_2.1.2.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rematch2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'cli' ...
** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object 'glue_collapse' is not exported by 'namespace:glue'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'cli'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cli'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/cli_2.0.2.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'cli' is not available for package 'gh'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/gh'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/gh_1.1.0.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gh’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'xfun' is not available for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/knitr_1.29.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'cli' is not available for package 'pkgbuild'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pkgbuild'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/pkgbuild_1.1.0.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgbuild’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'cli' is not available for package 'sessioninfo'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/sessioninfo'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/sessioninfo_1.1.1.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sessioninfo’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'gh', 'rematch2' are not available for package 'usethis'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/usethis'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/usethis_1.6.1.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'pkgbuild', 'sessioninfo' are not available for package 'rcmdcheck'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rcmdcheck'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/rcmdcheck_1.3.3.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'usethis', 'cli', 'ellipsis', 'pkgbuild', 'pkgload', 'rcmdcheck', 'sessioninfo' are not available for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0/downloaded_packages/devtools_2.3.1.tar.gz' komutunu çalıştırırken 1 durumu oluştu
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKMLzu0\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: have you tried to install the previous version of both packages? `devtools::install_version`

Comment: when I try to install devtools package I am getting this error "installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status"

Comment: You need to show me the whole error. The last sentence is not enough to understand the issue. Alternatively you can go here to install your packages: [caTools](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/caTools/), [gplots](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gplots/). From there you can download the tar.gz and install it directly.

Comment: When I try to install latest version of caTools and gplots both, I am getting version error like (you need to install newer R versions) . I am adding the error to my question.

Comment: Can you not update R - 3.3 is several years old. Also would help to translate those error messages

Comment: @RichardTelford Unfortunately I have a different user package and it does not work with newer R versions (newer than 3.5.0)

Comment: Alternative is to fix the package - maybe as simple as recompiling it